# Simple Pathfinding in Javascript Canvas - Think Adventure game

Tags: javascript, canvas, polygon, path-finding, adventure

I am trying to replicate the function in a point and click adventure game where a character needs to walk within a certain path without going outside the boundaries of the path.

Just as an example: I have this JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1ztzz6an/1/ that draws a polygon. What I want is for only the characters feet(Bottom part of the imported image) to only stay within the polygon. Here is the code:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var triangle = [{
    x: 71,
    y: 247
}, {
    x: 299,
    y: 313
}, {
    x: 520,
    y: 215
}, {
    x: 587,
    y: 49
}, {
    x: 468,
    y: 154
}, {
    x: 420,
    y: 36
}];



// define the polygon
function define(polygon) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(polygon[0].x, polygon[0].y);
    for (var i = 1; i < polygon.length; i++) {
        ctx.lineTo(polygon[i].x, polygon[i].y);
    }
    ctx.closePath();
}
define(triangle);
ctx.fill();
```

I have seen examples using tiles and such. But I want it to be within the polygon itself. Alternatively, if it is easier, I am willing to even look at the solution as a way to walk outside the polygons, as long as the players feet do not touch the polygons. Not sure which is better and which is easier.

Any help and example to get me going? Thank you!

Comment: **To get you started:** (1) Any movement on the canvas is achieved by clearing the canvas and redrawing everything (poly+playerImage) in their new positions. (2) You can let your player move their imported image by listening for `mousemove` events and redrawing your scene (the polygon) and then moving your player image by the distance the mouse has moved since the last mousemove. (3) You can test if the bottom of your image is inside the polygon by testing if the bottom-left and bottom-right corners of the image are inside the polygon. You can use `.isPointInPath` to test those 2 points.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of algorithms you can use to check that a given point (the player) is inside the polygon or not: **Raycasting** and **Winding Number**, they are both described in the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon).

Update: it looks like the [canvas API has this implemented for you](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/isPointInPath), see markE's comment above

Comment: Yeah, but this method won't work in iOS. If I used phonegap to compile to iOS it wouldn't use all the parameters. Is that correct?

Comment: I have never used phonegap so I don't know, but I'm sure you can implement the algorithm yourself if the built in version won't work.